# How to get data from list by condition in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have Class Model:

1. Class ProductInfo

   ```
    public class ProductInfo
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDProduct { get; set; }        
    public List<ProductImages> ProductImages { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Class ProductImages

   ```
    public class ProductImages
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }
    public Boolean ImgFlag { get; set; }
    }
   ```

I have data

[image]

This is how I get product information

```
    async Task ExecuteLoadProductCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            ProductInfos.Clear();
            var prodList = await productRepository.GetProductsAsync();
            foreach (var prod in prodList)
            {
                //Get Imgaes by condition
                //prod.Images = ProductImages()
                ProductInfos.Add(prod);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

**The first:**
How can I Binding Images with the condition ImgFlag = true in ContentPage Product.axml

**The Second:**
I have a ContentPage that shows ProductDetails.axml. I show the following information:
"Name": Name Product,... ---> This is fine. However I have an extra CarouselView. I want to show a list of images with the condition that ProductID = ID(ProductInfo)

This is how I pass the ProductDetail data

```
    public DashboardsViewModel()
    {
       LoadProductCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadProductCommand());
       ProductInfos = new ObservableCollection<ProductInfo>();

       ProductTappedView = new Command<ProductInfo>(OnViewDetailProduct);
    }

    private async void OnViewDetailProduct(ProductInfo prod)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailProduct(prod));
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1. don't add products without images to `ProductInfos`.  2. just set the `ItemsSource` of the Carousel to the `ProductImages` property of the selected `ProductInfo`

Comment: Thank you. I solved issue 2. However, issue 1: I don't want to remove the product without the image. But I want to get the image ImgFlag = true. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: you could use could filter out the items without images when you assign your ItemsSource, but this would effectively be two different lists of data

Comment: Thanks, I will find another solution